# Помощь с FullPage.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, page, fullpage

Не работает FullPage.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wrapper").fullpage();




  // sectionsColor:['red','blue','green'],
  // anchors:['firstPage','secondPage','3rdPage'],
  // menu:'#menu',




});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.back1 {
  background: url(img/back1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  height: 1000px;
}

.back2 {
  background: url(img/back2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  height: 1000px;
}

.back3 {
  background: url(img/back3.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css">

</head>

<body>



  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="section">
      <div class="back1">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
      <div class="back2">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
      <div class="back3">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 1):

Решено . Не был подключен файл script.js